# Unable to download the PDF file from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to download an .PDF file from a website : https://XXXXX/XXXX/XXXXXXX.pdf when user click's on link button. Below code is working fine in local but when I try to click on link button for downloading the file after deploying into server, First time it is working fire but next consecutive downloads, It is displaying as The XXXX.PDF download was interrupted or file cannot be downloaded.

try
{

```
         string fullFileName =string.Empty;
            LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
            string filepath = btn.CommandArgument;
            string fileName = btn.Text; 

        if (fileName != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
                           
            fullFileName = filePath +fileName ;

            int bytesToRead = 10000;

            // Buffer to read bytes in chunk size specified above
            byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];

            //string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullFileName);
            //Create a WebRequest to get the file
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | (SecurityProtocolType)768/*TLS1.1*/ | (SecurityProtocolType)3072/*TLS1.2*/;
            HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(fullFileName);
            

            //Create a response for this request
            HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();

            if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
                fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;

            //Get the Stream returned from the response
            stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();

            // prepare the response to the client. resp is the client Response
            var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;

            //Indicate the type of data being sent
            resp.ContentType = "application/PDF";

            //Name the file 
            resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
            resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());

            int length;
            do
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (resp.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // Read data into the buffer.
                    length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

                    // and write it out to the response's output stream
                    resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                    // Flush the data
                    resp.Flush();

                    //Clear the buffer
                    buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
                }
                else
                {
                    // cancel the download if client has disconnected
                    length = -1;
                }
            } while (length > 0); //Repeat until no data is read
        }
        else
        {
            lblFile.Text = "File Name is missing";
            lblFile.Visible = true;
        }
     }
       
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
    finally
    {

        if (stream != null)
        {
            //Close the input stream
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Can someone please guide me why it is failing in server